# How to compile multiple languages from command prompt?

Tags: windows, compilation, command, prompt

If I wanted to compile code in java, I go to environment variables and set the PATH variable to the bin of the jdk on my computer. Now my command prompt recognizes commands like "javac" and "java" and I can compile/run code without any issues.

But if I wanted to compile code in C/C++, suddenly commands such as "gcc" or "g++" are no longer recognized by my command prompt because the PATH variable was overwritten to the java location. I could change it back to the location of my C/C++ compilers, but then my command prompt would no longer recognize the java commands.

How can you make the command prompt recognize all commands? There must be a better way than changing environment variables every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append all needed paths to your `PATH` variable.  You will want to put them in order of priority, in case there are matches that may potentially be found on multiple path entries.

For example, for Windows:

```
set PATH=%JAVA_PATH%;%PATH%
set PATH=%CPP_PATH%;%PATH%
...
```

Or, as a single line:

```
set PATH=%JAVA_PATH%;%CPP_PATH%;...;%PATH%
```

(Hypothetical entries - substitute as appropriate.)

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly the answer I was looking for.